# jquery switching array list with radio buttons and checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, checkbox, radio-button

Is there any way to make this work?

I have 2 radio buttons and 7 checkboxes.

```
<body>
<input type="radio" id="upper">Uppercase
<input type="radio" id="lower">Lowercase<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="1" data-val=""> Monday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="2" data-val=""> Tuesday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="3" data-val=""> Wednesday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="4" data-val=""> Thursday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="5" data-val=""> Friday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="6" data-val=""> Saturday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="0" data-val=""> Sunday
</body>
```

When I chose "Uppercase" radio button, I'd like to use "var DAYS", and set value as "data-val".

For example,

```
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="1" data-val="MON">Monday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="2" data-val="TUE">Tuesday
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="0" data-val="SUN">Sunday
```

And when I chose "Lowercase", I'd like to use "var days", and set value as "data-val".

```
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="1" data-val="mon">Monday
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="2" data-val="tue">Tuesday
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
<input type="checkbox" name="days" id="0" data-val="sun">Sunday
```

I tried to make this happen as following way, but it doesn't wowrk.

```
<script>
var DAYS = ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU','FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN'];
var days = ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu','fri', 'sat', 'sun'];
if ($('#upper').prop('checked')) {
    $.each(DAYS, function (i, value) {
        var ID = parseInt($("input[ type='checkbox' ]").attr('id'));
        if (ID === i) {
            $("[ type='checkbox' ]").attr( 'data-val', value);
        }
    });
else if ($('#lower').prop('checked')) {
    $.each(days, function (i, value) {
        var ID = parseInt($("input[ type='checkbox' ]").attr('id'));
        if (ID === i) {
            $("input[ type='checkbox' ]").attr( 'data-val', value);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Could anyone help me with the following steps?

Please, no flames about my bad English.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your arrays inside an object you can use bracket notation to access them which will help to DRY up your code.

Firslty add a common class and value attribute to the `radio`:

```
<input type="radio" id="upper" value="upper" class="case-toggle">Uppercase
<input type="radio" id="lower" value="lower" class="case-toggle">Lowercase<br />
```

Then in JS:

```
var days = {
    upper: ['MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI', 'SAT', 'SUN'],
    lower: ['mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat', 'sun']
}

$('.case-toggle').change(function() {
    $.each(days[$(this).val()], function(i, item) {
        $('input[name="days"]').eq(i).data('val', item);
    });
});
```